# Pandas DataFrame filter rows using another DataFrame Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict1 = {'col1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A','B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B' ], 
       'col2':[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3 , 3], 
       'col3':[0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 0.85, 0.65, 0.75, 0.45, 0.55, 0.75 ],
       'col4':[100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict1)
df1

dict2 = {'col1': ['A', 'B' ], 
       'col2':[0.75, 0.65], 
       'col3':[1000, 2000 ],
       'col4':[0.8, 0.9]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict2)
df2
```

**In fastest way** how to filter df1 using df2,  depending on df1['col3'] >= df2['col2'] for equal col1s?

Intended outcome

```
>>> df1
  col1  col2  col3  col4
1    A     2  0.80   200
2    A     2  0.90   300
3    A     3  0.95   400
4    A     3  0.85   500
5    B     2  0.65   600
6    B     2  0.75   700
9    B     3  0.75  1000
```

My attempt gave the following error

```
>>> df1= df1[df1['col3'] >= float(df2[df2['col1']==df1['col1']]['col2'].values[0])]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/burcak/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py", line 64, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "/home/burcak/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 521, in wrapper
    raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Comment: Congratulations on asking `pandas` Question 170,000! @Burcak You have just won a new car! ;)

Answer (score 6):

I will do `merge`

```
out = df1.merge(df2[['col1','col2']], on = 'col1', suffixes = ('','1')).query('col3>=col21').drop('col21',1)

out
Out[15]: 
  col1  col2  col3  col4
1    A     2  0.80   200
2    A     2  0.90   300
3    A     3  0.95   400
4    A     3  0.85   500
5    B     2  0.65   600
6    B     2  0.75   700
9    B     3  0.75  1000
```

Or `reindex`

```
out = df1[df1['col3'] >= df2.set_index('col1')['col2'].reindex(df1['col1']).values]
Out[19]: 
  col1  col2  col3  col4
1    A     2  0.80   200
2    A     2  0.90   300
3    A     3  0.95   400
4    A     3  0.85   500
5    B     2  0.65   600
6    B     2  0.75   700
9    B     3  0.75  1000
```

You could also use `map`:

```
 df1.loc[df1.col3 >= df1.col1.map(df2.set_index("col1").col2)]
```

Comment: How is this col21 generated?

Comment: @burcak `df1.merge(df2[['col1','col2']], on = 'col1', suffixes = ('','1'))` look at the suffixes~ if duplicate column it will add the str at the end

Comment: My aim is ro reduce runtime

Comment: @burcak we provide multiple solution , you can check which one is better , I recommend map or reindex then

Comment: Yes, I time them and map solution gave the best runtime. Thanks @BEN_YO

Answer (score 3):

My method would be similar to @Ben_Yo 's merge answer, but more lines of code, but perhaps a little more straightforward.

You simply:

1. Merge the column in and create new dataframe `s`
2. Change the datafame `s` into a boolean series that returns `True` or `False` according to the condition, which in this case is `s['col3'] >= s['col2']`
3. Finally, pass `s` to `df1`, and the outcome will exclude rows that returned `False` in the boolean series `s`:

---

```
s = pd.merge(df1[['col1', 'col3']], df2[['col1', 'col2']], how='left', on='col1')
s = s['col3'] >= s['col2']
df1[s]
Out[1]: 
  col1  col2  col3  col4
1    A     2  0.80   200
2    A     2  0.90   300
3    A     3  0.95   400
4    A     3  0.85   500
5    B     2  0.65   600
6    B     2  0.75   700
9    B     3  0.75  1000
```